# Error: Could not find 'blob' in 'rusqlite'

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to read/write blob data from a .sqlite file using Rust and rusqlite; however, Cargo is telling me `blob` does not exist in rusqlite.
Here is the example code I was testing with from [the documentation](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.18.0/rusqlite/blob/index.html):

```rust
use rusqlite::blob::ZeroBlob;
use rusqlite::{Connection, DatabaseName, NO_PARAMS};
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom, Write};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let db = Connection::open_in_memory()?;
    db.execute_batch("CREATE TABLE test (content BLOB);")?;
    db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO test (content) VALUES (ZEROBLOB(10))",
        NO_PARAMS,
    )?;

    let rowid = db.last_insert_rowid();
    let mut blob = db.blob_open(DatabaseName::Main, "test", "content", rowid, false)?;

    /* snip */

    Ok(())
}
```

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
# ...

[dependencies]

    [dependencies.rusqlite]
    version = "0.18.0"
    features = ["bundled"]
```

It should be noted that I had to use the `bundled` method as the standard `rusqlite = "0.18.0"` did not work for me. The documentation says `blob` is only supposed to work with SQLite 3.7.4 and higher, but I don't see any reason that I would have an older version, and I also don't know how to check. Any ideas?

Comment: `features = ["blob"]` ...

Comment: @Stargateur This works! Thank you!